# Profiling F# function -- profiler doesn't see any of the calls of the function's body. Why?

Tags: .net, performance, f#, profiling

I wrote the following function

```
let getTriangles maxPerimeter =
    let mutable count = 0
    for c in 1..maxPerimeter do
        let cc = (int64 (c*c))
        for b in 1..Math.Min(c-1, maxPerimeter-c-1) do
            let bb = (int64 (b*b))
            for a in 1..Math.Min(maxPerimeter-c-b, (int (Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(float (cc+1L-bb)))))) do
                let aa = (int64 (a*a))
                if cc + 1L = aa + bb then
                    count <- count + 1
    count
```

and now it's time to tune it up.

To do so, I've installed `dot Trace Performance` and ran it over my application for a very big `maxPerimeter`, so as to make sure the program would take a while to run.

This is what I get:

[image]

As you may imagine, what I actually wanted to know is how the usage time is distributed *inside* `getTriangles'` function body, so this doesn't seem to be of particular help. I've tried turning off code optimizations in the `Build` pane, but it doesn't seem to help me a bit.

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. How should I go about to profile this function?
3. Is this F# or CLR specific behavior?

All the profiling experience I have is with Java, so I may be a bit off here on the CLR world. I've also dabbled with ANTS Performance but the result was the same.

Comment: Clearly essentially all the time is being spent by the last three lines of the inner loop, which the profiler won't tell you if it does not have line-level resolution. A tiny fraction of time goes into various `Math.` routines. It may not be showing you those if profiling is not enabled for them.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about dotTrace, I use ANTS Performance Profiler as I've found it works pretty well with F#; I've been using the new version (v8) recently to profile my [fsharp-tools](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-tools) projects.

Once you complete a profiling run in ANTS Performance Profiler and the results are displayed, the default view only shows methods for which you have the sources (i.e., the .exe/.dll you're profiling has a .pdb alongside it which points to some valid source location on your machine). You can use the drop-down (see the screenshot) to show all methods, which is pretty useful for F# code; because you're passing functions around, the execution stack tends to go in and out of the libraries you may be using, so viewing "All Methods" gives a better picture of what your code is actually doing, and how code from an external library might be affecting the performance of your code.

[image: ANTS Performance Profiler v8 screenshot, profiling F# code (fsharp-tools)]

That said -- F# has two different kinds of `for` loops; they look similar but are actually quite different under the hood. The one you used (`for x in y do`) is roughly equivalent to a `foreach` loop in C# -- that is, the loop compiles down to an iterator which pulls each value from some sequence of values. The second, much faster kind of loop (`for i = x to y do` or `for i = x downto y do`) compiles down to very simple IL, just like you'd get with a `for` loop in C#, Java, C, etc.

Here's a modified version of your function which uses the second kind of `for` loop. In this case, it's only slightly faster (`13.749s` vs. `13.520s`, `N = 5000` on my laptop), but it is without question the way you want to write your code if you're doing any tight loops over numerical ranges.

```
let getTriangles' maxPerimeter =
    let mutable count = 0
    for c = 1 to maxPerimeter do
        let cc = int64 (c * c)
        for b = 1 to min (c-1) (maxPerimeter-c-1) do
            let bb = int64 (b * b)
            for a = 1 to min (maxPerimeter-c-b) (int <| ceil (sqrt <| float (cc+1L-bb))) do
                let aa = int64 (a * a)
                if cc + 1L = aa + bb then
                    count <- count + 1
    count
```

As far as behavior within the function, ANTS Performance Profiler can also give you line-level timings (but only for methods you have the source for). I compiled and profiled your function and my modified version (with `maxPerimeter = 2000`):

[image: ANTS Performance Profiler v8, line-level timings for F# project]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jORA0.png . See? There's nothing there. As it happens with both profilers it can only mean it's something with the .NET framework, I'd dare to say.

Comment: @devouredelysium I don't think it's a profiler issue -- when I profiled your code to get the second screenshot, nearly all of the execution time was taken by the `getTriangles` and `getTriangles'` functions; IIRC, my version only called one external function, which was `Math.Sqrt` -- everything else was inlined into the function. However, if you really want to see _everything_, go into the options menu in ANTS Performance Profiler and uncheck the box for hiding insignificant methods; the profiler runs more slowly, but it'll record absolutely everything.

Comment: @devouredelysium Also, if you wouldn't mind -- please take a second to post your screenshot to the [ANTS Performance Profiler Support Forum](http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewforum.php?f=167). I doubt that the `NaN` values on the right are supposed to be there.